# Cannot start Database in Docker

Tags: mysql, database, docker

When I run the command `docker-compose up`, I got this error for container

```
    db_1   | 2021-02-02 12:34:35+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.
    db_1   | 2021-02-02 12:34:35+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
    db_1   | 2021-02-02 12:34:35+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.22-1debian10 started.
    db_1   | 2021-02-02 12:34:35+09:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
    db_1   | mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno 17 - File exists)
    db_1   | 2021-02-02T12:34:35.842317+09:00 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22) initializing of server in progress as process 43
    db_1   | 2021-02-02T12:34:35.843699+09:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file './mysql-error.log' for error logging: Permission denied
    db_1   | 2021-02-02T12:34:35.843730+09:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
    db_1   | 2021-02-02T12:34:35.843738+09:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
    db_1   | 2021-02-02T12:34:35.843818+09:00 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

And web-sp-infra_db_1 exited with code 1.
Even when I check the command docker-compose ps, the container `web-sp-infra_db_1` has the State Exit 1

```
       Name                     Command               State                            Ports                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
web-sp-infra_app_1   docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up       9000/tcp                                             
web-sp-infra_db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Exit 1                                                        
web-sp-infra_web_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up       0.0.0.0:3001->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp, 80/tcp
```

Therefore, when I run docker-compose exec db bash, it causes the ERROR: No container found for db_1

Command docker-compose images

```
    Container           Repository       Tag       Image Id       Size  
------------------------------------------------------------------------
web-sp-infra_app_1   web-sp-infra_app   latest   bd3c13e0dd66   553.7 MB
web-sp-infra_db_1    web-sp-infra_db    latest   5276d7c919b1   545.3 MB
web-sp-infra_web_1   web-sp-infra_web   latest   7b04c3a6e430   630.8 MB
```

Could you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno 17 - File exists)" <<<---

Comment: @MitchWheat Excuse me, how to fix that error "Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno 17 - File exists)" in docker?

Comment: Are you using a mysql official image or public image? could you tipe the name of image here?

Comment: @FrancisconSantos I added to the question for docker-compose images. Please check it

Comment: I recommend  you to removing the /var/lib/mysql directory in the Dockerfile using RUN rm -rf / var / lib / mysql, or changing the msyql data directory in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file, changing the "datadir" parameter.

Comment: @FrancisconSantos when I run the command docker run rm -rf /var/lib/mysql, it said Unable to find image 'rm:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for rm, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

Comment: Could you put here your docker-compose without any password?

Comment: @FrancisconSantos Sorry, I don't understand well, what should I need to put? Only result from docker-compose command?

Comment: I need your docker-compose file.

Comment: @FrancisconSantos This one for db
  db:
    build: ./docker/mysql
    volumes:
      - ./db/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./db/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 33307:3306

Comment: Do you need to persiste data after a docker-comspose down? I mean, is this a development environment? If yes, just remove this line "volumes: - ./db/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"

Comment: But, if you're trying to start a production environment, you need to check directory permission "./db/mysql_data", it's be couse you container image is trying to start, but it don't have permission to change any data inside the directory "./db/mysql_data"